# flash tends to make objects 0.05-0.5 pixels off from values I enter in properties

Tags: flash, properties

How can I adjust flash so it values can only be whole numbers for dimensions and positions? For some reason flash likes to adjust the numbers I enter in the properties flash changes the number slightly. i.e i set the width to 500 and it'll adjust it to 500.05 or 499.05.

Comment: Yah this happens to me all the time.. Mostly when zoomed in. Generally though if you just correct it once it should be fine. Also this isn't really a coding question but rather a UI issue.

Comment: zooming out doesn't help in my case T_T

Comment: Does it happen even after manually typing in the value you actually want into the properties panel more than once or twice?

Comment: yes that's exactly when its happening. never happens when I position in as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about positioning not being to an absolute pixel, then you could just round off the `x` and `y` properties.

Easiest way to do this if you're not too confident with AS3 is to just put these two lines on the first frame of the MovieClip:

```
x = Math.round(x);
y = Math.round(y);
```

Comment: this works but Im looking for a gui solution for my animated movie clips that do not have code associated with them.

Comment: I dunno normally if the problem you're describing occurs for me I just re-enter the value I want (or remove the .05) and it's fine.

Comment: -_- that worked...if I enter a number and hit enter it changes the number as described. If I re-enter a new number same thing. but If I delete the .05 it works.